# Discord.py Userinfo Command error: In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm having some trouble in my userinfo command.

Here's my command's code:

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx , member: discord.Member = None):
    
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    roles = [role for role in member.roles if role.name != '@everyone']
    
    
    uiembed = discord.Embed(description = member.mention, timestamp = ctx.message.created_at , color = 0x146da8)
    uiembed.set_author(name = f'{member}' , icon_url = member.avatar_url)
    
    developer = (530894795384815616 , 619621027873423360)
    
    uiembed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    uiembed.set_footer(text=f"ID:{member.id}" , icon_url = "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/788938397568991234/790040765346217984/unknown.png")
    
    uiembed.add_field(name = 'Joined' , value = member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p"))
    uiembed.add_field(name = 'Registered' , value = member.created_at.strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y %I:%M %p") , inline = True)
    
    uiembed.add_field(name = f'Roles ({len(roles)})' , value = ''.join([role.mention for role in roles[1:]][::-1]) , inline = False)
    uiembed.add_field(name = 'Key permissions' , value = "Coming soon" , inline = False)
    
    if member == ctx.guild.owner and developer:
        uiembed.add_field(name = 'Acknowledgements' , value = 'Owner , Developer')
        
    elif member.id == ctx.guild.owner:
        uiembed.add_field(name = 'Acknowledgements' , value = 'Owner')
        
    elif member.id in developer:
        uiembed.add_field(name = 'Acknowledgements' , value = 'Developer')
        
    else:
        pass
    
    
    await ctx.send(embed = uiembed)
```

And here's the error I have been encountering for the past 2 days:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fakeblob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/fakeblob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/fakeblob/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required
```

If you could help me fix the error, it would really mean a lot to me.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you provided, please add the whole process of creating the embed

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I updated the code, it shows the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have empty strings as the `name` or `value` in added fields.

The issue lies with this line:

```
uiembed.add_field(name=..., value=''.join([role.mention for role in roles[1:]][::-1]), inline=...)
```

If the user only has 1 role other than the default role, the list comprehension you've made will be empty.
This means that `.join(...` will return an empty string: `''`, which as I mentioned before, will raise the error that you're seeing:

```
>>> ''.join([])
''
```

There are a couple ways to go about fixing this, but at the end of the day, you want to have a value there no matter what.
How you go about this is up to you, but I would personally do something like so:

```
role_mentions = [role.mentions for role in roles[1:]][::-1]
text = "Nothing was found..." if len(role_mentions) == 0 else ', '.join(role_mentions)

uiembed.add_field(name=..., value=text, inline=...)
```

I'm not sure whether the splice you added (`[1:]`)was for another reason or not, but that would also fix the issue if the user had at least 1 role other than `@everyone`.

I also added the `,`  as a joining character for preference, but feel free to remove that.

Comment: My remove statment, would only remove the @everyone, because it looked ugly

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're saying, then list comprehension you did earlier already got rid of the `@everyone` and that means that you wouldn't need to add in the `[1:]` on a list that already excluded it.